# Integrate Twilio chat function in ANDROID

Tags: android, chat, twilio

I made an account on Twilio console for accessing their Chat services.
I generated a access token with "client Identity" as its reference name.

I downloaded the project from https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android.

After performing requisite steps such as gradle file sync and adding google-services.json

I am unable to figure out what could be the URL ?

```
def ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVICE_URL = project.hasProperty(ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVICE_URL) ? "\""+project.getProperty(ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVICE_URL)+"\"" :"\"http://localhost:8000/token.php/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzllOGRlODAwM2U3ZTdlMjk2NzY5ZWUxZTQ0MDJhNDkxLTE1MDA4OTE2ODgiLCJpc3MiOiJTSzllOGRlODAwM2U3ZTdlMjk2NzY5ZWUxZTQ0MDJhNDkxIiwic3ViIjoiQUNkZTFkZGJjYjZiYTE5MTBhMmExMDA2ZThmNTE1MDIzZiIsImV4cCI6MTUwMDg5NTI4OCwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoiY2hhdCIsImlwX21lc3NhZ2luZyI6eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3NpZCI6IklTM2E4OTVkNGQyNjdlNDZjNjgxZmU0NDBlZGZhNDkzZmUiLCJlbmRwb2ludF9pZCI6ImlwLW1lc3NhZ2luZy1kZW1vOmNoYXQ6ZGVtby1kZXZpY2UifX19.J5dkegxkoo9fWaN0embyAcShZ2831InLbuOX6JI8jvU\""
```

Since, I haven't setup a web service I am try to access through localhost.

After successfully installation of app, UI appears with login button along with edittext field with reference name, which I mention at Twilio console.
On clicking the login button, my app crashes throwing an error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Token cannot be null in ChatClient constructor
```

apparently, my url is not appropriate, if anyone have worked on Twilio chat application, please do guide me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to setup a web application that can serve access tokens to your Android app. I would follow the [instructions as part of the quickstart guide to starting Programmable Chat on Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/quickstart-android#set-up-the-server-app).

The instructions get you to install and run a [PHP project that can generate access tokens for the various Twilio services](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-php). The instructions get you to run the application on `localhost:8000`. Once you have that application running your `ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVICE_URL` should be `http://localhost:8000/token.php`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for helping me in establishing server setup.
But, after going through mentioned tutorials i have successfully setup a server and for accessing in mobile SDK i launched ngrok also.
Using "forwarding url" from ngrok. The Final URL I made :

"https://28cf8a89.ngrok.io/token.php/<copied_token_from_console>"

Still token "Token cannot be null in ChatClient constructor" error persist.
Please do help me in this.

Comment: Two things: you don't need the token copied from the console for that URL. That URL is supposed to create the token for you. Secondly, if you restart ngrok then the URL will change, do you still have the same ngrok tunnel? Can you log what the response is?

Comment: Can I get your email id, so i can ask for your help.
Mine email id : rishabh@healthscion.com

Comment: My URL in GRADLE FILE :
def ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVICE_URL = project.hasProperty('https://d726598b.ngrok.io/token.php') ? "\""+project.getProperty('https://d726598b.ngrok.io/token.php')+"\"" : "\"https://d726598b.ngrok.io/token.php\""

Comment: Log statement of localhost server: with "qwerty" as a client Identity in console
[Wed Jul 26 12:20:35 2017] 127.0.0.1:56772 [200]: /token.php?identity=qwerty
Log statement of ngrok server:
Forwarding                    https://d726598b.ngrok.io -> localhost:8000 
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                                                                   
                              1       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    

GET /token.php                 200 OK